# ReactJS.NET is not initialized correctly when using IIS Express

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-express, reactjs.net

I'm using ReactJS.NET (version 3.0.0) to render/initialize client-side components in an MVC application, but upon calling the `Html.ReactInitJavaScript()` helper method I get the following exception at run-time:

> [TinyIoCResolutionException: Unable to resolve type: React.IReactEnvironment]
>      React.TinyIoC.TinyIoCContainer.ResolveInternal(TypeRegistration registration, NamedParameterOverloads parameters, ResolveOptions options) +833
>      React.TinyIoC.TinyIoCContainer.Resolve(Type resolveType) +60
>      React.TinyIoC.TinyIoCContainer.Resolve() +56
>      React.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelperExtensions.get_Environment() +53
>
> [ReactNotInitialisedException: ReactJS.NET has not been initialised correctly.]
>      React.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelperExtensions.get_Environment() +107
>      React.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelperExtensions.ReactInitJavaScript(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, Boolean clientOnly) +141

However, this is only happening in *IIS Express* when NOT in debug mode. When debugging, or using Local IIS, I don't get this error.

ReactJS.NET uses `WebActivatorEx` to initialize during PreApplicationStart. Are there known issues/workarounds for getting `WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod` to trigger in IIS Express?

Below is my `ReactConfig` in case it helps. I'm not using the supplied version of `react` and I'm using `webpack` for transformation/bundling.

```
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(ReactConfig), "Configure")]
namespace MyApplication
{
    public static class ReactConfig
    {
        public static void Configure()
        {
            ReactSiteConfiguration.Configuration
                .SetLoadBabel(false)
                .SetLoadReact(false)
                .AddScriptWithoutTransform("~/dist/bundle.server.js");
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

FWIW, I've tried replacing `WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod` with `System.Web.PreApplicationStartMethod` and `OwinStartup` to no avail.

Comment: What version of React are you on?